# How to display sqlitedata into tablelayout in dynamic form

Tags: android

I have sqlite data and it updated every time whenever user click on save button and i want to show this data in to a table layout manner dynamically, e.g whenever user click on save button the table layout display the data from sqlite data base.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at this [Notepad application](http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/notepad/index.html..)

Comment: Thanks for your reply but i see the notepad code and there is no table layout in it.

Comment: In that Sample data are populated in List View same way u have to populate for Table Layout..

Comment: actually the thing is i have to show the data in a row manner having 5 columns in it and whenever save button click, it add another row from database restoring the previous in a view. So again my question is whenever i click the save button m getting the data in string form, so how to use this string to show the data in table layout manner or some other manner